# Using an expression's result as a private var in Swift, eg: private var xxx = Theme.current == .light

Tags: swift, variables

Is there a difference between these two code snippets?

Snippet 1:

```swift
private var isLight = Theme.current == .light
```

Snippet 2:

```swift
private var isLight: Bool {
 Theme.current == .light
}
```

As far as I understand, for snippet 2, when you try too access isLight, the expression `Theme.current == .light` is going to be evaluated every time you access this property.

What about snippet 1, then?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's different:

```swift
enum Theme {
    case light
    case dark
    
    static var current: Theme {
        print("Accessing current")
        return .light
    }
}

class ThemeTest {
    var isLight: Bool = Theme.current == .light
    var isLight2: Bool {
        return Theme.current == .light
    }
}
let themeTest = ThemeTest()
for _ in 0..<1000 {
    print("Accessing isLight")
    let _ = themeTest.isLight
    print("Accessing isLight2")
    let _ = themeTest.isLight2
}
```

Results:

```
Accessing current
Accessing isLight
Accessing isLight2
Accessing current
Accessing isLight
Accessing isLight2
Accessing current
...
Accessing isLight
Accessing isLight2
Accessing current
```